# I have this timer circuit. Push and release vs push and hold give me different times

Tags: timer, capacitance, delay, charge, time

I have a timer circuit which I slightly modified from the one in this [link](http://www.eleccircuit.com/timer-set-for-30-minutes/#comment-192508)

I have an image below of what my circuit looks like.

My problem is this: When I push my start button and immediately let go, the circuit gives me 14 minutes like I want. When I push and hold my start button for a few seconds and then release, I get something much longer than 14 minutes.

I believe it has something to do with the capacitor taking some time to fully charge but there is only wire resistance and the current limitation of the power supply (1.3 Amps). I don't know how to account for this. Ideally I want to push the button and get it to fully charge. If I hold it for a few seconds, I don't want it to affect the time more than a few seconds at best.

[image]

Comment: When you press S2 you are probably triggering the short-circuit protection in the LM7812, therefore it's delivering much less than the expected 1.3A. Put a large cap at the output of your regulator, larger than the 1000uF you have in parallel with S3. It will be able to deliver much more current faster than the regulator.

Comment: I would sure like to see some current limiting in series with S2 and S3. It will slow down your on/off times, but \$10\Omega\$ would only be ~50ms. Your push buttons will thank you.

Comment: The resistors I have are 0.25watts. I'm worried the resistor may burn. Same with 270ohm resistor Vicente mentioned for the LED. I put 1k because anything less heats up and starts to smell or burn. The push buttons are industrial, they should be able to handle the current.

Comment: I will add the capacitors to see if it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your original circuit does not have a clear discharge path with known resistance and therefore its discharge time is difficult to assess. Chances are you have achieved 14 minutes through trial and error of different base resistors. Other factor that comes into consideration is sudden supply voltage drop when the transistor triggers current through the relay winding. This could explain why holding the switch and letting voltage stabilize gives a tad more charge to the 1000uF capacitor, and since discharge path is of unknown *high* impedance, this results in a higher overall time until transistors cut off.

Instead of letting the capacitor discharge through the Darlington base, create a known resistance discharge route by inserting a resistor in parallel with your capacitor. You should also add capacitors close to the 7812s like in the following schematic due to changes in load. Your LED resistor value should be decreased and base resistor value should be increased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4gc6m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To calculate the needed value of 390k, assume transistors cut off when the capacitor charge is lower than 1.4V, and that base current can be neglected. This means it needs to discharge from 12V to 1.4V, or 11.67% of initial voltage. This takes roughly 2.15 RC time constants, according to the following plot.

[image]

Let C be 1000uF, we have the following equation:

$$
2.15\times R \times 1000u=14min \times 60s/min
$$

R then equates 390.7k, or roughly 390k.

Comment: Getting 390K is fine. But can you please elaborate on how it solves the problem asked. I mean, the problem was the difference in discharge time between long press and short press of switch S2. How this gets solved here?

Comment: @user3219492 Added an introductory paragraph with possible explanation. Candidly though, I don't say this solution is bullet-proof (given any other circuit imperfections), OP should test it and track back to us.

Answer (score 0):

> There was, for example, the theory that A’Tuin had come from nowhere and would continue at a uniform crawl, or steady gait, into nowhere, for all time. This theory was popular among academics.

*Terry Pratchett, The Colour of Magic, 1983*

This time it's not turtles all the way down, but rather RC circuits all the way down.

Here we have *two* timers: a short (≈0.1s) timer based on C2-R4 that controls Q1's charging of C1 via R2. C1-R1 determine the delay of approximately a dozen minutes. The time is approximate, to get slightly less approximate timing, C1 needs to be 10x larger, R1 10x smaller. M1-M2 could be instead packaged inside of a CD4007, and then we could add  a current mirror on the bottom of the pair, and a current source on top, the gain would be higher, and the time delay would be more stable.

M1 and M2 form a MOS differential pair and thus have extremely low input current - such that C1 and C3 are effectively only loaded by their resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYL0gb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are much better timing solutions using CMOS 555, CD4000-series counter-oscillator chips, or really anything designed in the last 20 years. But a "lo-fi" discrete design is certainly fun to put together. Today probably the best price-to-performance ratio solution would be a $0.10 OTP (one-time-programmable) Padauk microcontroller. They cost even less in volume, the firmware is trivial.